# Vue Unit test - child components & i18n

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils, vue-i18n

I am entering the world of application testing and I have some doubts about how to test, mainly because of the languages ​​and child components.

Basically, the first tests I'm trying to run is to cover whether the listing pages have the right data.

The structure I have at the moment is the following structure -

components structure

```
baseTable
  |- columnHeader
  |- rowRoute
```

Depending on the route the user is on, in the `baseTable` component the table body is dynamically imported.

Example, the active page is users, so it will import rowUsers.

The first error that occurs to me, is that in the columnHeader component it presents the error

> `vm.$t is not a function`

the second error is in the component `rowUsers` in which it says

> `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

the third error is that the `rowUsers` component does not exist.

> `expect( wrapper.find( rowUsers ).exists()).toBe( true );`
> Expected: true
> Received: false

I tried to pass the i18n and the router-link on the wrapper, but it still didn't work.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import baseTable from '@/components/bundles/tables/baseTable';
import rowUsers from '@/components/dynamic/tables/rowUsers';
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n';

describe( 'Lists', () => {

    it( 'Users list', () => {
        // mock from user
        const fields = [{
            email: 'user@mail.com',
            name: 'user 1',
            role: 'admin'
        }];

        const wrapper = shallowMount( baseTable, {
            propsData: {
                url: 'users',
                headers: [ null, 'name', 'email', 'role' ],
                fields: fields,
                row: 'Users'
            },
            stubs: ['router-link'],
            i18n
        });

        expect( wrapper.find( rowUsers ).exists()).toBe( true );
    })

})
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock `$t` like this:

```
shallowMount( baseTable, {
  mocks: {
    $t: (msg) => msg
  }
})
```

or you can add a global mock to avoid repeated code in every test file:

```
import VueTestUtils from "@vue/test-utils"

VueTestUtils.config.mocks["$t"] = msg => msg
```

https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/mocking-global-objects.html#example-with-vue-i18n

Answer (score 1):

The first and second errors might just be related to a missing Vue-router dependency in the Vue-test-utils vm, especially if you're testing a component on its own while Vue-router was imported at the root of your app.

Have you tried importing Vue-router in your test file, before mounting your component?

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

As for the third error, this is just syntax, `wrapper.find()` expect a CSS selector, to select your component use `wrapper.findComponent()`, also `shallowMount` will stub ALL your child components by default, so you might want to use `mount` instead:

```
const wrapper = mount( baseTable, {
  propsData: {
    url: 'users',
    headers: [ null, 'name', 'email', 'role' ],
    fields: fields,
    row: 'Users'
  },
  stubs: ['router-link'],
  i18n
});

expect(wrapper.findComponent(rowUsers).exists()).toBe(true);
```