# Use jest along i18n in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, i18next, vue-i18n

*Thanks for looking at my question (junior dev going nuts).*

Recently I added i18n to my Vuejs (comp. API) app for translation, which worked flawlessly. However, after pushing, I realized the **jest suit broke**. The original parsing error was fixed by adding
`"^vuetify$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"` to my jest config in package.json.

However after that, this error emerged and tortures me for multiple days... >:(

● DudDialog.vue › Test state update › displays the form fields correctly
**TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function**
... and many more, but this one ^ seems to be the core issue ...

**How can I get i18n to work inside the jest-test?** I looked into **stubbing** i18n but only found solutions using vitest or in react. (Which i wasn't able to adapt) How would i do that correctly?

*Please save me! Mental health is declining :{*

```
//DudDialog.spec.js
import { config, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import DudDialog from "@/components/DudsView/DudDialog.vue";
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";
import { Dud } from "@/store/dudClass";
import { DIALOG_STATES } from "@/miscellaneous/constants";
import { translations } from "@/miscellaneous/translations";

describe("DudDialog.vue", () => {
  let component;
  const pinia = createPinia();
  let dudProp;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    setActivePinia(pinia);
    mountDudDialog();
  });

  function mountDudDialog() {
    component = mount(DudDialog, {
      global: {
        stubs: [
          "v-app",
          "v-main",
          "v-dialog",
          "v-row",
          "v-card",
          "v-toolbar",
          "v-text-field",
          "v-select",
          "v-textarea",
          "v-col",
          "v-form",
          "v-btn",
          "v-card-actions",
        ],
        plugins: [pinia],
      },
      props: {
        dud: dudProp,
      },
    });
  }

  beforeAll(() => {
    config.global.renderStubDefaultSlot = true;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    config.global.renderStubDefaultSlot = false;
  });

  it("renders component", () => {
    expect(component.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe("Test state create", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      dudProp = new Dud("TheDud");
      mountDudDialog();
      component.vm.openDudDialog(DIALOG_STATES.CREATE);
      await component.vm.$nextTick();
    });

    it("displays correct title", () => {
      const titleElement = component.find(".dialogToolbar");
      expect(titleElement.attributes().title).toContain(
        "Neuen Blindgänger erfassen"
      );
    });

    it("displays the form fields correctly", () => {
      const typeField = component.find("[label='Typ']");
      expect(typeField.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(typeField.element.__vnode.props.modelValue).toBe(undefined);
    });

    it("displays correct buttons", () => {
      const createButton = component.find(".createButton");
      const dismissButton = component.find(".dismissButton");
      const saveButton = component.find(".saveButton");
      const okButton = component.find(".okButton");
      expect(createButton.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(dismissButton.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(saveButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      expect(okButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      /*
      const createFunction = jest.spyOn(component.vm, "onClickCreateDud");
      createButton.trigger("click");
      expect(createFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();*/
    });
  });

  describe("Test state read", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      dudProp = new Dud(0, "TheDud");
      mountDudDialog();
      component.vm.openDudDialog(DIALOG_STATES.READ);
      await component.vm.$nextTick();
    });

    it("displays correct title", () => {
      const titleElement = component.find(".dialogToolbar");
      expect(titleElement.attributes().title).toContain("TheDud");
    });

    it("displays the form fields correctly", () => {
      const typeField = component.find("[label='Name']");
      expect(typeField.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(typeField.element.__vnode.props.modelValue).toBe("TheDud");
    });

    it("displays correct buttons", () => {
      const createButton = component.find(".createButton");
      const dismissButton = component.find(".dismissButton");
      const saveButton = component.find(".saveButton");
      const okButton = component.find(".okButton");
      expect(createButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      expect(dismissButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      expect(saveButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      expect(okButton.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  describe("Test state update", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      dudProp = new Dud(0, "TheDud");
      mountDudDialog();
      component.vm.openDudDialog(DIALOG_STATES.UPDATE);
      await component.vm.$nextTick();
    });

    it("displays correct title", () => {
      const titleElement = component.find(".dialogToolbar");
      expect(titleElement.attributes().title).toContain("TheDud bearbeiten");
    });

    it("displays the form fields correctly", () => {
      const typeField = component.find("[label='Name']");
      expect(typeField.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(typeField.element.__vnode.props.modelValue).toBe("TheDud");
    });

    it("displays correct buttons", () => {
      const createButton = component.find(".createButton");
      const dismissButton = component.find(".dismissButton");
      const saveButton = component.find(".saveButton");
      const okButton = component.find(".okButton");
      expect(createButton.exists()).toBe(false);
      expect(dismissButton.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(saveButton.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(okButton.exists()).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi. Firstly, if you're feeling bad then step away from the computer - no code is worth getting yourself down over. As for helping you solve the problem, I'd suggest you post example code as it's too difficult for people to help you if you're just describing the problem. Anywho from a bit of Googling of the TypeError you've posted, it looks like there could a solution here: https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/350

Comment: Consider posting what you tried and what exactly did not work, this way you have more chances to solve a problem because a user who answers won't need to untangle this from scratch. Generally you just mock a module to the point it fits the way the original one is used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Unit test - child components & i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580287/vue-unit-test-child-components-i18n)

Answer (score 0):

Adding i18n to the plugins in mount() fixed it.‍♀️

```
mount(DudDialog, {
      global: {
        stubs: [
          "v-app",
          "v-main",
          "v-dialog",
          "v-row",
          "v-card",
          "v-toolbar",
          "v-text-field",
          "v-select",
          "v-textarea",
          "v-col",
          "v-form",
          "v-btn",
          "v-card-actions",
        ],
        plugins: [pinia, i18n],
      },
      props: {
        dud: dudProp,
      },
    });
```